# how to get curly brackets url value in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have configured my URL like below

```
[Route("abc-yyy-{value}")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I want to get the {value} to a string. can someone please guide me on how to do that in .NET core? Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend you to read the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing you will find your answer. Go in "Complex segments" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply ensure that the variable name you are using in the curly braces is present in the signature of that controller method.  For example:

```
[Route("abc-yyy-{value}")]
public IActionResult MyControllerMethod(string value) {
    // you can now use the string variable "value"

    return Ok();
}
```

And your URL is just something like:

https://myhost.com/controllername/abc-yyy-hello

Resulting in the string variable "value" being set to "hello".